# Looking for some English to Katakana advice for the name Marilou

Tags: katakana

I have two different versions:

Marilou: マリル
Sargado: サーガド

or

Marilou: マリルー
Sargado: サルガド

Would appreciate some advice on which Katakan best matches the names. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd like to know what language the name originates from, and how it would be pronounced. My first guess is French, but I really don't know, and it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Spanish

> マリル　サルガード

If you are French

> マリルー　サーガド

Would be close to the original sounds, but any of them telling the difference of Marilou マ**リ** with the **R**and **ル** with the **L**.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the correct pronunciation of your name, according to you.

For example if the　Mari part is pronounced 'may-ree' then メアリールー would be better. But if the Mari part is pronounced like 'marry'　then マリルー is good.

I would say that サルガード is a better choice as it's closer to the way Japanese tend to render 'r' sounds into katakana. So my suggestion is:

メアリールー・サルガード (for a 'may-ree' pronunciation)
マリルー・サルガード (for a 'marry' pronunciation)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you pronounce your family name, but you might want to also consider the following.

> サーガード
>   サルガード

The most likely choice might be

> マリルー サーガード

Although slightly unfortunate, most people seems to katakanize names with the easy way out and just prolong easy sounds instead of the harder to pronounce sounds.